# Calculating the rotation vector of a sphere

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, physics

I'm trying to calculate the axis of rotation of a ball which is moving and spinning at the same time, i.e. I want the vector along the axis that the ball is spinning on.

For every frame I know the x, y and z locations of 3 specific points on the surface of the sphere. I assume that by looking at how these 3 points have moved in successive frames, you can calculate the axis of rotation of the ball, however I have very little experience with this kind of maths, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From the first position you can calculate the center of the ball using the 3 points on the surface. Let's call it S. Then you just need one point on the surface of the ball, A, from 2 successive frames. For every frame you calculate vector `S - A`. You will get vectors v1 and v2. And then you need to calculate vector multiplication `v1 x v2` and you get vector n that is parallel to the axis of rotation.

Comment: Beware that given three points on the sphere, the center can be at two mirrored locations, so you could find several solutions. A fourth point or a specific orientation rule would be welcome to solve the ambiguity.

Comment: I should have mentioned, that the 3 points are on a sphere where the center is the origin (0,0,0), so this simplifies things somewhat! So in that case, going by the first answer: The locations p1 and p2 of a point p would be the same as the vectors v1 and v2, so I just need to multiply these to get the vector parallel to the axis of rotation?

Comment: exactly. also, note that the order of the vectors is important. vector from the first frame must be first.

Comment: @cdm One point is not enough. You will miss the rotation component passing through this point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that the direction a position vector moves in will always be perpendicular to the axis of rotation. Therefore, if you have two position vectors v1 and v2 at successive times (for the same point), use

[image]

This gives you an equation with three unknowns (the components of w, the rotation axis). If you then plug in all three points you have knowledge of you should be able to solve these simultaneous equations and work out w.